# How to extract Neo4j graph aggregation through Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, cypher

I have been struggling to get this to work and the documentation and examples on the official neo4j-spark-connector [page](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) are confusing me.

I have a aggregation query working on Neo4j browser.

```
MATCH p=(h:Hashtag {hashtag:'#ios'})-[r:HASHTAG]-()-[:HASHTAG]-(h2) return count(r) as cnt,h2 order by cnt desc
```

I don't have a very solid understanding of different data structures in Spark. I have tried examples from [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/) and [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector)

Couple examples of what I have tried:

```
val rdd = neo.cypher("MATCH ((h:Hashtag {hashtag:'#ios'})-[r:HASHTAG]-()-[r:HASHTAG]-(h2)) RETURN h2.hashtag").loadRowRdd

val graphQuery = """MATCH (h:Hashtag)-[r:HASHTAG]-()-[r:HASHTAG]-(h2:Hashtag) where h.id = 1502 RETURN h2"""
val graph: Graph[Long, String] = neo.rels(graphQuery).partitions(7).batch(200).loadGraph

graph.vertices.count
```

Returns this error:

> Name: Unknown
>
> Message: Unable to retrieve error!
>
> StackTrace:

The data on my neo4j database is very simple, its made of only one type of relationship. 
        (Tweet)-[HASHTAGS]->(Hashtag)

I'm simply trying to return a dataframe that can list hashtags 2 steps away from a given hashtag and count their frequency. Please help!